# Allocating a Column’s value to a different Column in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, accounting

I have a report that I’m doing up and I’m having some issues with.
Basically, if there exists a value in Cost Center 0
[image: image image 1479×805 116 KB]

I need to allocate that value to the other columns (e.g. 10, 11, 12, 13, 20 …):
[image]

By these percentage rates (Table is Default Cost Center Allocation):
[image]

And zero out that 0 Cost center column.

So using the row account 5040 under the Discounts category, you have a value of $3,371:
[image]
[image]

The math I need is for all cost centers but for example cost center 10 would be:
$1,392 (original number for cost center 10) + ($3,371 * 10%)

Then I would follow the same convention of allocation to each cost center (e.g. 10, 11, 12, 13, 20 …) and finally the cost center 0 would display empty as it has been allocated to other cost centers.

Here is breakdown:
[image]

In excel:

[image]

Here it is simplified; regardless if associated accounts (1) has data, I need each field to contain the associated lookup value like example (2)
[image]

PBI:
https://forum.enterprisedna.co/uploads/short-url/imfl4RENrOZbxpnaezeAYeII4r8.pbix

Comment: Your images are too small to read what you try to do. I believe this is best to be done in mquery by adding the calculated columns as you need them..

Comment: thanks for your response, do you mind elaborating on your idea?

Comment: sorry about images, the text describes what is happening. if cost center = 0 then allocate by a percentage rate (lookup value) to all other cost centers

Comment: I do very much need assistance. I've been at this for days; I attached a mock report if you are still willing to help on this. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know already how to use mquery.

Hereby the script to manipulate the data. I could not use your pbi file as the master table was not giving any data so I copied form PowerBI to excel and did a new import.

The first 4 lines are the import so you do not need it.

1. Filter to get only the cost centre 0 rows
2. merge on the cost unit to get the % on how to divide the money.
3. Expand only needed columns
4. Add the columns Alloc where the calculation is happening
5. Remove columns not needed from orig table and rename the other columns to match orig table
6. Get all other rows from the orig table with cost center <> 0

End result is extra rows in your orig table which you need to show in your report. The script you need to append to your existing GLTransactions table

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\PowerBI\GLTransactions.xlsx"), null, true),
    GLTransactions_Sheet = Source{[Item="GLTransactions",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(GLTransactions_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"bkjrcode", Int64.Type}, {"ACCOUNT", Int64.Type}, {"dagbknr", Int64.Type}, {"COST CENTER", Int64.Type}, {"COST UNIT", Int64.Type}, {"docdate", type datetime}, {"PK Cost Center", Int64.Type}, {"PK Cost Unit", Int64.Type}, {"Segment Driver", type text}, {"Dollars with Allocation", Int64.Type}, {"Merged", Int64.Type}, {"Default Cost Center Allocation.Value", type number}, {"Cost Center Desc", type text}, {"bdr_hfl", Int64.Type}}),


    GetOnlyCostCenter0 = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([COST CENTER] = 0)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(GetOnlyCostCenter0, each [Dollars with Allocation] > 0),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows1", {"COST UNIT"}, #"Cost Unit Allocation", {"Cost unit"}, "Cost Unit Allocation", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Cost Unit Allocation" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Cost Unit Allocation", {"Cost Center", "Description", "PK Cost Units Allocation", "Value"}, {"Cost Center.1", "Description", "PK Cost Units Allocation", "Value"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Cost Unit Allocation", "Alloc", each [Dollars with Allocation] * [Value]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"COST CENTER", "Dollars with Allocation", "Cost Center Desc","PK Cost Center","PK Cost Unit","Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Cost Center.1", "Cost Center"}, {"Description", "Cost Center Desc"}, {"Alloc", "Dollars with Allocation"}, {"PK Cost Units Allocation", "PK Cost Unit"}}),
    GetExclCostCenter0 = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([COST CENTER] <> 0)),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Renamed Columns", GetExclCostCenter0})
in
    #"Appended Query" // Here you have your new Transactions(gbkmut) table. It includes rows for each cost allocation
```

Comment: I had to tweak this a bit but this is exactly what I needed; you're a saint sir. Thank you so much for your help